# TypeError: Cannot read property 'spirit' of undefined -- The property can be read upon page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

```
const QueueItem = (props) => {
  let spirit = props.drink.spirit ? (
    <div>
      {props.drink.spiritquantity} | {props.drink.spirit}
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div> No Spirit </div>
  );

  let liqueur = props.drink.liqueur ? (
    <div>
      {props.drink.liqueurquantity} | {props.drink.liqueur}
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div> No Liqueur </div>
  );

  let mixer = props.drink.mixer ? (
    <div>
      {props.drink.mixerquantity} | {props.drink.mixer}
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div> No Mixer </div>
  );

  let cocktail = props.drink.cocktail ? (
    <div>
      {props.drink.user[0].name}
      <div>{props.drink.cocktail}</div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      {" "}
      {props.drink.user[0].name}
      <div>{spirit}</div>
      <div>{mixer}</div>
      <div>{liqueur}</div>
    </div>
  );
  let logged = (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="warning"
        onClick={() => props.handleDeleteDrink(props.drink._id)}
      >
        Remove From Queue
      </Button>{" "}
    </div>
  );

  if (props.user.email === "admin@gmail.com") {
    return (
      <div className="drink-item">
        <div>{cocktail}</div>
        <div>{logged}</div>
      </div>
    );
  } else if (props.user) {
    let logged =
      props.user._id === props.drink.user[0]._id ? (
        <div>
          <Button
            variant="warning"
            onClick={() => props.handleDeleteDrink(props.drink._id)}
          >
            Remove From Queue
          </Button>{" "}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <input type="hidden" />
      );
    return (
      <div className="drink-item">
        <div>{cocktail}</div>
        <div>{logged}</div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="drink-item">
        <div>{cocktail}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default QueueItem;
```

I get property undefined on all of the variables defined at the top.  Upon page reload they all load up properly.  It is always on the fresh item being created and added to my DB. (MERN)

Items are added in my top level like this.

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.handleAddDrink(this.state.drinkInfo);
    console.log("HANDLE SUBMIT", this.state.drinkInfo);
  };


  handleAddDrink = async (drinkIngredients) => {
    console.log(`DRINK WILL BE ${drinkIngredients}`);
    drinkIngredients.user = userService.getUser();
    const newDrink = await drinkService.create(drinkIngredients);
    this.setState((state) => ({
      drinks: [...state.drinks, newDrink],
    }));
  };
```

When my form is submitted these functions are fired and the drink is properly added to the DB.  My form submit button doesn't redirect at the moment but I would love if anyone could help me understand how to get the props in the first component to be defined on the first render of the page without requiring a page refresh.

Props are passed down like this

```
          <Route
            exact
            path="/queue"
            render={({ history }) => (
              <QueuePage
                queue={this.state.queue}
                drinks={this.state.drinks}
                handleDeleteDrink={this.handleDeleteDrink}
                handleNewDrinkClick={this.handleNewDrinkClick}
                handleLogout={this.handleLogout}
                user={this.state.user}
                history={history}
              />
            )}
          />
```

```
const QueuePage = (props) => (
  <div className="QueuePage">
    <NavBar user={props.user} handleLogout={props.handleLogout} />
    <div className="queue">
      <QueueList
        queue={props.queue}
        drinks={props.drinks}
        handleDeleteDrink={props.handleDeleteDrink}
        user={props.user}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

```
 return (
    <div className="QueueList">
      <h1 className="queue-title">Drink Queue</h1>
      <div className="drink-list">
        {props.drinks.map((drink) => (
          <QueueItem
            drink={drink}
            handleDeleteDrink={props.handleDeleteDrink}
            user={props.user}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

repo: github.com/tshuldberg/coastr

Comment: Can you please show how you are passing the `props` to `<QueueItem />` component? Thanks!

Comment: that would be much easier to read if you edited the information into your question

Answer (score 0):

The error-message says it cannot read property `spirit` of `undefined`, which means, your `props.drink` seems to be undefined.

What value does `this.state.drinks` have initially? It might happen during the first render cycle, when `this.state.drinks` is still undefined and therefor you are passing through `undefined`.

Did you try to output the actual values of your props throughout the component tree? Try logging them to the console and see what the actual values are, you are receiving in your components

For example in your `QueryItem`-Component before `let spirit = props.drink.spirit ? (` do this:

```
console.log(props.drink)
```

to see what you got there

Comment: Thanks for the help! So it reads spirit of undefined upon the first render of my QueuePage.  If I refresh the page it reads that value properly and performs the check I'm asking of it.  Upon drink creation then navigating to the QueuePage where the QueueItem is rendered for each drink in drinks array from state, logging props.drink is the drink object for each drink in the array other than the final one which returns undefined.  When I refresh the page that final drink object is logged properly.

Comment: I assume some kind of a timing issue. But not 100% sure since I cannot see where `this.state.drinks` gets fed from. What you could (and should) do in general is checking for undefined like this `if (typeof props.drink !== 'undefined') { //do your stuff here }` before working with your variables. Alternatively make sure to not pass `undefined`-values by setting an initial state

Comment: My source code is at the bottom of my post if you're interested in a closer look.  Sounds good! I gave that a try originally but was running into some other issues but yeah my state is initialized as empty strings for all of those variables. I guess I could also avoid this by just adjusting the initialized value to a truthy string? So that it is never read as undefined.

Comment: Your code snippets don't show your initial state, but two things that come to my mind here: first if you are assuming an array of drinks, why are you initializing `this.state.drinks` as an empty string and not an empty array? second: since you are initializing it with an empty string but receive undefined there might be some step in between where it gets undefined. Maybe your function call `drinkService.create(drinkIngredients);` in your `handleAddDrink`-Handler returns undefined and then `this.setState` sets it as value of `this.state.drinks`.